# How can I fix my weapon models when they become completely black?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

After a game of Deathmatch/Arms Race for a warmup, I usually play a round of  Competitive matchmaking. Around halfway into the match, my gun skins usually become silhouettes of the model. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

[image: Black silhouette gun model]

Comment: I've personally encountered issues where the correct skin fails to load and it instead uses the default. I've not encountered what you describe though...  My theory is it's not loading the skin but I'm not sure how to fix it. You might try setting `cl_forcepreload` to `1` in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gun skins / camos seem to cause crashes for some PC configurations. Disabling your skins does nothing, since OTHER PLAYERS use theirs....

All you have to do is the following in video settings:

- Model/Texture Detail to LOW
- Shader Detail to HIGH